# Child views not getting equal space with `layout_weight` attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to create the following XML layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am expecting the first `TextView` and the inner `LinearLayout` to take up equal amounts of space but that is not happening. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSr9w.jpg).

Can someone please suggest any fixes?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. Do you have a diagram for how you want your UI to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Hello" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Hello" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Hello" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your weighting has worked correctly in your image.

The left over space has been evenly been distributed between the 2 views with weights.

The problem is `layout_weight` affects the left over space **after** the content has taken all the space it needs, it does not directly control the overall size.

Better to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) then set [layout_constraintWidth_percent](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#percent-dimension) to 50% for each item